Django ORM, similar queries
Help me remove duplicates please, I’ve already tried everything, documentation, chatGPT, I don’t know how to remove it, it’s just that when I access the .html attribute a new request to the database is generated
I'm using django-mailbox, I couldn't specify it because the rating is less than 1500. Models:  https://django-mailbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/django_mailbox/models.html
messagesDB = Message.objects.filter(mailbox=mailbox).select_related('mailbox', 'message_used').prefetch_related(Prefetch('attachments', queryset=MessageAttachment.objects.all(), to_attr='all_attachments'))
for message in messagesDB:
    print(message.html)

SELECT ••• FROM "django_mailbox_messageattachment" WHERE "django_mailbox_messageattachment"."id" = 44 LIMIT 21
 13 similar queries.


**SELECT "django_mailbox_messageattachment"."id",
       "django_mailbox_messageattachment"."message_id",
       "django_mailbox_messageattachment"."headers",
       "django_mailbox_messageattachment"."document"
  FROM "django_mailbox_messageattachment"
 WHERE "django_mailbox_messageattachment"."id" = 44
 LIMIT 21 13 similar queries.**


C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\dashboard-APxxHYiU\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py in __call__(80)
  return self.application(environ, start_response)

C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\dashboard-APxxHYiU\lib\site-packages\whitenoise\middleware.py in __call__(124)
  return self.get_response(request)

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py in inner(79)
  return func(*args, **kwds)

C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\dashboard-APxxHYiU\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py in view(104)
  return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\dashboard-APxxHYiU\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py in dispatch(73)
  return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\dashboard-APxxHYiU\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py in dispatch(109)
  return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\dashboard-APxxHYiU\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py in dispatch(143)
  return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\dashboard-APxxHYiU\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py in get(226)
  context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)

C:\Users\user\Desktop\Задачник\ProjectsDashboard\dashboard\timetable\views.py in get_context_data(2109)
  messagesDB = self.get_message_telegram(self.mailbox)

C:\Users\user\Desktop\Задачник\ProjectsDashboard\dashboard\timetable\views.py in get_message_telegram(2058)
  print(message.html)

C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\dashboard-APxxHYiU\lib\site-packages\django_mailbox\models.py in html(671)
  self.get_email_object(), 'text', 'html'

C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\dashboard-APxxHYiU\lib\site-packages\django_mailbox\models.py in get_email_object(783)
  self._email_object = self._rehydrate(flat)

C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\dashboard-APxxHYiU\lib\site-packages\django_mailbox\models.py in _rehydrate(683)
  self._rehydrate(part)

C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\dashboard-APxxHYiU\lib\site-packages\django_mailbox\models.py in _rehydrate(683)
  self._rehydrate(part)

C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\dashboard-APxxHYiU\lib\site-packages\django_mailbox\models.py in _rehydrate(687)
  attachment = MessageAttachment.objects.get(

C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\dashboard-APxxHYiU\lib\site-packages\cacheops\query.py in get(327)
  return qs._no_monkey.get(qs, *args, **kwargs)

C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\dashboard-APxxHYiU\lib\site-packages\cacheops\query.py in _fetch_all(250)
  return self._no_monkey._fetch_all(self)


Please don't repost your question, edit it instead to provide any clarifications.

Currently the Message and MessageAttachment are too losely couples, it would require a change to django-mailbox itself.

@AbdulAzizBarkat, okay, I'm sorry

@willeM_VanOnsem  thank you, I understand you) it's a pity
